# Firebase Firestore rules : How to check if the reference to document contains the uid of the requester?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore database with a collection `users` that contains informations about my users. The id of each documents is the user uid assigned by Firebase Auth.

I have another collection called `rooms` that contains a field `users` which is a list of document references, those references points to user document.

Here is a room document in which there is a field which is a list of references to users collection. The letters you see after `/users/` is the uid of the user and also the document id of the user in collection users.

[image]

I also have a field called `owner` which is a document reference to a `user` in collection `users`.

I want to create a firebase rule where a user can only retrieve rooms in which he is.

```
    match /rooms/{room} {
      allow read : if isLoggedIn() && isInRoom();
      allow create : if isLoggedIn();
      allow delete, update : if isLoggedIn() && isInRoom() && isRoomOwner();
    }

  function isLoggedIn() {
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
  }
  
  function isInRoom() {
    return request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
  }

  function isRoomOwner() {
    return "users/"+request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
  }
```

So here, `resource.data` points to a room document and so `resource.data.users` is the array of user reference seen in the previous picture. And so `resource.data.owner` points to a single document reference of a user in users collection.

But as I have written it in this example, it's not working since the `request.auth.uid` returns a uid and `resource.data.users` returns a reference, something like `users/uid`. I tried to change `resource.data.users` to `"users/" + resource.data.users` but it's not clean.

I have the same problem with the `isRoomOwner` function but here, the `resource.data.owner` is just a document reference and not a list of document reference.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It will be easier to understand what the problem is if you show examples of actual documents.  It's not very clear what you mean by "resource.data.users returns a reference".  Do you mean it is a field of type reference that points to some other document?  Or something else, such as a string?  Be specific about the contents.

Comment: I agree with @DougStevenson, normally something like this should work `request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId`, where `userId` is a field inside the document, which contains the desired uid

Comment: Are you able to edit the question to show the information I requested about your documents?

Comment: @DougStevenson, There you go, I tried to explain a bit more and give details to my question.

Comment: Does providing the full path work? `/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) == resource.data.owner` (note: this is a path, not a string, so don't wrap it in quotes)

Comment: It's not possible to compare a string to a document reference using ==.  You will have to either convert the string to a reference (a Path type object), or convert the reference to a string, and compare them with another value of the same type.  Use the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/index-all) to help learn how things work.

Comment: Please upload a diagram of your DB model to let us understand visually your question and what you’re trying to solve, also let us know if what is commented has been useful.

Answer (score 0):

As samthecodingman suggested in his answer, I can compare directly the paths. So I can do something like that :

```
match /companies/{companyId} {

allow read: if /databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid) == resource.data.owner

}
```

or like that :

```
match /companies/{companyId} {
  allow read: if isOwner(resource.data.owner, request.auth.uid);
}

function isOwner(owner, userId) {
   return path('/databases/(default)/documents/users/' + userId) == owner;
}
```